# Post required `<td>` only in Express.js

Tags: javascript, html, express, body-parser

```html
{{#if results}}
  <form method="post">
    <div class="table">
      <table border="1" style="width:100%;background-color:white;color:black;padding-top:10px;">
        <tr>
          <tr>
            <th>RegNo</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Mail ID</th>
            <th>Phone No</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
          {{#each results}}
          <tr>
            <td name="id" > {{ID}}</td>
            <td>{{name}}</td>
            <td>{{department_name}}</td>
            <td name="email" > {{email_id}} </td>
            <td>{{phone_num}}</td>
            <td><button style="border:1;" class="button" formaction="block">Block</button></td>
            <td><button style="border:1;" class="button" formaction="remove">Remove</button></td>
          </tr>
        </tr>
      </form>
      {{/each}}
    </table>
    {{else}}
  <div> No User exists</div>
{{/if}}
```

The result contains a length n data. When I click the block I need to get the two pieces of data from the `<td>`, so in the server:

```
router.post('/block', ensureAutheticated, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  var regno = req.body.id;
  var email = req.body.email;
  console.log(regno, email);
});
```

But this is not working. `<td>` can’t put the name in there. How to do this? A click on the block returns that row’s data or table data required only to the server.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add two hidden inputs, because TD's can't pass value through form

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ID}}" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{email_id}}" />
```

Comment: Wait... are you trying to send data from node to handlebars ?
If yes, you probably arent sending the object result with those values (id and email_id)

Comment: it returns all the {{id}} id from that page name="id" this  satisfied values

Comment: try to fix the html tags, and close the {{/each}} at the TR instead of form, and i'm not so sure about what problem you're trying to solve :/